# Is it possible to modify an object on a list in a parent frame in R?

Tags: r, list, assign

I'm working on an R package that has a number of functions that follow a non-R-standard practice of modifying in place the object passed in as an argument.  This normally works OK, but fails when the object to be modified is on a list.

An function to give an example of the form of the assignments:

```
myFun<-function(x){
  xn <- deparse(substitute(x))
  ev <- parent.frame()
  # would do real stuff here ..
  # instead set simple value to modify local copy
  x[[1]]<-"b"
  # assign in parent frame
  if (exists(xn, envir = ev)) 
  on.exit(assign(xn, x, pos = ev))
  # return invisibly 
  invisible(x)
}
```

This works:

```
> myObj <-list("a")
> myFun(myObj)
> myObj
[[1]]
[1] "b"
```

But it does not work if the object is a member of a list:

```
> myObj <-list("a")
> myList<-list(myObj,myObj)
> myFun(myList[[1]])
> myList
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] "a"


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] "a"
```

After reading answers to other questions here, I see the docs for `assign` clearly state:

`assign does not dispatch assignment methods, so it cannot be used to set elements of vectors, names, attributes, etc.`

Since there is an existing codebase using these functions, we cannot abandon the modify-in-place syntax. Does anyone have suggestions for workarounds or alternative approaches for modifying objects which are members of a list in a parent frame?

UPDATE:

I've considered trying to roll my own assignment function, something like:

```
assignToListInEnv<-function(name,env,value){
  # assume name is something like "myList[[1]]"
  #check for brackets
  index<-regexpr('[[',name,fixed=TRUE)[1]
  if(index>0){
    lname<-substr(name,0,index-1)
    #check that it exists
    if (exists(lname,where=env)){
      target<-get(lname,pos=env)
      # make sure it is a list
      if (is.list(target)){
        eval(parse(text=paste('target',substr(name,index,999),'<-value',sep='')))
        assign(lname, target, pos = env)
      } else {
        stop('object ',lname,' is not a list in environment ',env)
      }
    } else {
      stop('unable to locate object ',lname,' in frame ',env)
    }
  }
}
```

But it seems horrible brittle, would need to handle many more cases (`$` and `[` as well as `[[`) and would probably still fail for `[[x]]` because `x` would be evaluated in the wrong frame...

Comment: The first task will be to locate them by name and you have not provided any guidance about how the R interpreter is supposed to find it/them. It is supposed to page through all the items in the workspace looking for ones that have names-attributes that contain the targets? I suspect you need to learn more about how to use environments or Reference Classes.

Comment: I guess I don't understand the first part of you comment. I'm assuming that `myFun` doesn't know the 'real' name of the `myObj` argument passed in, just its class.  Thanks for the suggestion to learn about Reference Classes, I'm not familiar with them. I like that they seem closer to Java classes, which seems appropriate for this use case. Is there a source beyond the man page to learn about them? Are you suggesting that `myObj` should be re-implemented as a Reference Class?

Comment: You seem to want to change component-"a" to be "b" (if it exists?) in all leaves of `myList`, but are not wanting to give the function the names of both of these items?

Comment: Oh, the 'a' to 'b' is just supposed to be an example of making an arbitrary modification to `myObj`.  The goal is to have `myFun` be able to modify `myObj` when it is passed directly (working) or when it is passed in as an element of a list (not working).  The problem is that in the first case `xn='myObj'` and in the second `xn='mylist[[1]]` and `assign` can't parse the later.

Comment: There is already a modifyList function. To be applied effectively here you would need to disclose what sort of structure would be assumed to exist in these list elements.

Answer (score 2):

*Since it was in the first search results to my query, here's my solution :*

You can use `paste()` with "<<-" to create an expression which will assign the value to your list element when evaluated.

```r
assignToListInEnv<-function(name, value, env = parent.frame()){
  cl <- as.list(match.call())
  lang <- str2lang(paste(cl["name"], "<<-", cl["value"]))
  eval(lang, envir = env)
}
```

EDIT : *revisiting this answer because it got a vote up*

I'm not sure why I used `<<-` instead of `<-`. If using the 'env' argument, `<<-`with assign to the parent.frame of that env.

So if you always want it to be the first parent.frame it can just be :

```r
assignToListInParentFrame<-function(name, value){
  cl <- as.list(match.call())
  paste(cl["name"], "<<-", cl["value"]) |> 
    str2lang() |>
    eval()
}
```

and if you want to precise in which env to modify the list :

```r
assignToListInEnv<-function(name, value, env){
  cl <- as.list(match.call())
  paste(cl["name"], "<-", cl["value"]) |>
    str2lang() |>
    eval(envir = env)
}
```