# Assign element to list in parent frame

Tags: r

Assume I have the following function:

```
f1 <- function()
{
  get.var <- function(v)
  {
    for(n in 1:sys.nframe())
    {
      varName <- deparse(substitute(v, env = parent.frame(n)))
      if(varName != "v")
      {
        break
      }
    }
    return(list(name = varName, n = n))
  }

  f2 <- function(v)
  {
    print(v)
    # get original variable name and environment
    obj <- get.var(v)
    #below doesn't work as expected - this is where q$a and q$b would be updated
    assign(obj$name, v + 1, env = parent.frame(obj$n))
  }

  f3 <- function(v){ f2(v) }
  f4 <- function(v){ f3(v) }

  q <- list(a = 2, b = 3)

  f4(q$a)
  f3(q$b)
}
```

How can I update the value of `q$a` and `q$b` from `f2`? The situation is that a similar routine is called in some of my code to validate a number of arguments in a nested list. If a value is incorrect the list element needs to be updated to reflect the correct value. It's certainly an ugly way to do it but unfortunately I cannot pass the entire list to each and every validation function.

A somewhat similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16045340/is-it-possible-to-modify-an-object-on-a-list-in-a-parent-frame-in-r) but the user was passing in a list element instead.

Comment: You can try `q$b <<- TRUE`.

Comment: Good point. I've updated the code so you can see why that isn't possible in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `assign(obj$name, v + 1, env = parent.frame(obj$n))`, I replaced this with `eval(parse(text = sprintf("%s <- %d", obj$name, v + 1)), envir = parent.frame(obj$n))`

It is horrendously ugly, but it works.